# Hidden DIV and id naming structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that displays one div at a time while hiding the previous shown div. When a button is clicked, the counter variable increases by one and the naming of the div id's are "step1", "step2", "step3", etc. Here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        $('html').addClass('js'); // prevent hiding divs on DOM ready from 'flashing'
        $(function() {
                $('#toggle_value').click(function() {
                $('div','#hiddendiv')
                        // to stop current animations - clicking really fast could originally
                        // cause more than one div to show
                        .stop()
                        // hide all divs in the container
                        .hide()
                        // filter to only the div in questio
                        .filter( function() { return this.id.match('step' + counter); })
                        // show the div
                        .show()
                        // prevent default anchor click event
                        return false;
                });
        });
</script>
```

This is where the variable is being incremented when clicked:

```
<div class="toggle_button">
        <a href="#" onClick="counter = counter + 1" id="toggle_value"></a>
</div>
```

Here is my hidden div:

```
<div id='hiddendiv'>
        <div id="step1" class="display">
                <p>step 1 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="step2" class="display">
                <p>step 2 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="step3" class="display">
                <p>step 3 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="step4" class="display">
                <p>step 4 text</p>
        </div>     
        <div id="step5" class="display">
                <p>step 5 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="step6" class="display">
                <p>step 6 text</p>
        </div>     
        <div id="step7" class="display">
                <p>step 7 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="step8" class="display">
                <p>step 8 text</p>
        </div>     
        <div id="step9" class="display">
                <p>step 9 text</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="step10" class="display">
                <p>step 10 text</p>
        </div>     
        <div id="step11" class="display">
                <p>step 11 text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

The script works wonderfully and does what it needs, until id's with double digits and ending with a "0" (10, 20, 30, 40, etc...). For example: when the counter = 1, div id step1 and div id step10 are being shown on the page. When the counter = 10, only div id step10 is being shown. Div id step11 is shown at the appropriate time so I have narrowed it down to double digits ending in 0. I will never have more than 100 steps so only ending double digits or less are being used.

Are 0's at the end of a div id being ignored and being seen step1 and step10? I know you can't use a numeric value at the beginning of a id but it also states any number of [0-9] after the alphabetic character.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using *match()*, just check for equality:

```
// filter to only the div in question
.filter( function() { return this.id == 'step' + counter; })
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TAQZQ/**

[*match()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is intended for searching a string with a regular expression and returning the matches.

Comment: Thank you Andy and Michael, that works. Thanks Andy for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `this.id.match` as it will try to match anywhere in the ID. Instead, try `this.id =` as follows:

```
.filter( function() { return this.id == 'step' + counter; })
```